# Solarized colors in st (simple terminal)

Tags: colors, terminal-emulator, suckless-terminal

I want to use [st](https://github.com/suckless/st) with [solarized](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/blob/master/xresources-colors-solarized/Xresources) colors like I can with `urxvt` (of course this is done via `.Xresources`, in `st` the colors are defined in a header file). I've tried to put the colors in `st`'s config file (config.h), but the colors are "used for the wrong things" in `st` (eg. dircolors and colors in `vim` are rearranged relative to `urxvt`).

I think I have to modify the escape sequences used by `st`, but I'm not getting anywhere. Can anyone offer me a hint on how to apply the solarized colors to `st`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In st tip (and the 0.3 release) it's not necessary to edit st.c, just insert the solarized colors in config.h. It seems that both st.c and config.h has changed since I asked this question.

Answer (score 3):

For those wanting an example of `st`'s `config.h` with Solarized colours see his Gist: https://gist.github.com/gregf/5279175

Answer (score 1):

I have no prior experience with st other than using it, but from glancing at the source I think I have found the parts that are relevant.
I presumed that by *use solarized colors* you meant that you want all applications that use *default blue* to instead use *solarized blue*.

You will need to make some changes to the source in st.c rather than just config.h.
dc is a *global* variable that is an instance of the DC struct, each `dc.cols[i]` corresponds to a color to use.

The first 16 colors within `config.h` colorname are loaded via `XAllocNamedcolor` within the function `xloadcols(void)`, these are inserted into the first 16 positions (0 to 15) within `dc.col`.

These correspond to ansi escape sequence colours, for more see [ANSI Escape Code::Colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).

You would need to change this funtionality within `xloadcols(void)`, specifically the first for loop.
Instead of using `XAllocNamedColor` you could instead use `XAllocColor` (you can see an example of this in the second for loop), this allows you to specify the rgb of each color to be inserted at each position (instead of loading an already known colour from a name).

For the hex values see [solarized.vim](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/blob/528a59f26d12278698bb946f8fb82a63711eec21/colors/solarized.vim) specifically lines 98 through 116 where the hex values are specified.

The rest of `dc.cols` is allocated within a for loop, also found within `xloadcols(void)`, you probably shouldn't need to change this although it means some applications may use these colors rather than your solarized ones.

As for the default background and foreground colors these are set within config.h, lines 40 and below.
each `#define name index` defines dc.col[index] is to be used for name, for example `DefaultBg` specifies the background color of the terminal.

Comment: Why do you recommend that I use the srgb rather than hex colors in solarized.vim?

Comment: Didn't see the hex color listing, corrected answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solarized is now available as an official patch against `config.def.h`:

https://st.suckless.org/patches/solarized/