# Execute semicolon separated commands passed to the -e flag of st (Simple Terminal)

Tags: bash, terminal, read, suckless-terminal

**NOTE:** `st` is the actual name of the terminal emulator in my question - https://st.suckless.org/.

---

I want to create a shortcut that if pressed, pops up st and displays the translation of the word in the clipboard.

I tried using this, but is exits immediately and gives an error:

```
$ st -e "trans $(xclip -o) -t en; read"`
child finished with error '256'
```

But the same works with `xterm` just as expected:

```
$ xterm -e "trans $(xclip -o) -t en; read"
```

Using only one command as the `-e` option of st works, but I need to execute read or something like that after trans so the terminal won`t close immediately.

Is this a bug in st or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Oh god another terminal - https://st.suckless.org/

Comment: It did actually already clarify that in the question title, @slm.

Comment: @JdeBP - I don't know if that's a euphemism  or what. I've never heard of this terminal before in 30+ yrs. The project's about shows it as ~10yrs (2008).

Comment: I have; and we've had questions dealing with it for over half that time. [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50769/) [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318262/) [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348221/)

Comment: @JdeBP - 4 out of 145k is backing up my position 8-). I mean no disrespect to the project, I just hadn't ever heard of it, and assumed, perhaps incorrectly that others would be in the same boat as I.

Comment: So did the questioner, which is why xe already explained what it was in the question title.  (-:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-e` option is a compatibility mechanism in *simple terminal*.  The command and arguments that you pass, with or without `-e`, are executed directly, by simple terminal forking and then [running `execvp()` in the child process](https://git.suckless.org/st/file/st.c.html#l722) on exactly the command and arguments it is given.  There's no shell involved, and the arguments passed to `st` are sent on exactly as-is to the target program.

You have passed everything all as one argument.  So simple terminal is actually trying to run a command named, literally, `trans $(xclip -o) -t en; read` (if single quoted, or that modified by whatever the result of the expansion is if you use double quotes). Obviously, you have no command named that.

To use a shell command line — such as you have here with expansions, shell built-in commands, and shell command syntax — you have to explicitly invoke a shell to understand it:

```
st -e sh -c 'trans "$(xclip -o)" -t en; read'
```

This runs `st` which starts an `sh` shell which runs a short shell script, which contains your commands.

Comment: @JdeBP Whoa there :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the man page for `st`:

```
st [-aiv] [-c class] [-f font] [-g geometry] [-n name] [-o iofile] [-T title] 
[-t title] [-l line] [-w windowid] [[-e] command [arguments...]]


-e command [ arguments ... ]
      st executes command instead of the shell.  If this is used it must be 
      the last option on the command line, as in xterm / rxvt. This option 
      is only intended for compatibility, and all the remaining arguments 
      are used as a command even without it.
```

I would agree with @Kusalananda that this switch is only intended to take a single command and nothing as complex as what you're trying to perform.

So for this you need to pass a shell in as the `-e` argument to `st` and then pass your commands in as a secondary set of arguments to the more capable shell:

```
$ st <other args> -e sh -c '....'
$ st <other args> -e bash -c '....'
```

#### References

- [st man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/st)